# User registration and User profile

Tags: microservices

I have a scenario

1. I have developed a user registration (endpoint: /api/user) microservice with Cosmos DB (SQL API)
2. Now, there is a new development of user profile management (endpoint: /api/user/{id}).

What would be the best solution to keep these 2 endpoints

1. Both the endpoints will be inside 1 microservice and use the same Cosmos DB (SQL API)
2. Both the endpoints will be in a different microservice with a different database.

Thanks in Advance.
Binjan

Answer (score 0):

we must think in functional perspective here, we can group multiple endpoint which may connect with one DB and another group of endpoint which may connect to another DB. Now thinking of above scenario it certainly makes sense to point to same DB or same controller.
If your services endpoint is performing different action and have different endpoint
as well, you may consider another DB to perform CRUD.